# Как скорректировать позицию элемента

Tags: bootstrap

У меня есть 2 элемента: Well, с какой-то информацией внутри и кнопка расположенная под ним, каким образом можно "надвинуть" кнопку на Well как показано на скрине?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот коды элементов:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-2" align="center">
      <div class="well" align="center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <br><b>Here</b>
        </br>u can find simple text
      </div>
      <!--EO Well--->
      <div class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Click here</div>
    </div>
    <!--EO Col--->
  </div>
  <!--EO Row--->
</div>
<!--EO Container--->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте `margin-top`

```css
.button {
  margin-top: -45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-2" align="center">
      <div class="well" align="center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <br><b>Here</b>
        </br>u can find simple text
      </div>
      <!--EO Well--->
      <div class="btn btn-danger btn-lg button">Click here</div>
    </div>
    <!--EO Col--->
  </div>
  <!--EO Row--->
</div>
<!--EO Container--->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А если например есть 3 таких элемента и надо сдвинуть только средний, как получить доступ именно к нему?

Comment: @ДимаСвободин пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01g61dub/)